# Where am I going wrong? When I try to go farther than this they stop being equal to each other.

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $$5+8+11+ \dots +(3n+2)=\cfrac{n(3n+7)}{2}\;,$$

then

$$5+8+11+ \dots +(3n+2)+\big(2(3n+1)+2\big)=\cfrac{(n+1)(3n+8)}{2}\;.$$

Comment: What are you aiming for? What is the question exactly?

Comment: $\sum_{i =1}^{n} (3i + 2 ) = \left(3 \sum_{i=1}^{n} i \right) + 2n = \cfrac{3n(n+1)}{2} + 2n = \cfrac{3n^2 + 7n }{2} = \cfrac{n(3n+7)}{2} $ 

This is pretty clear. Either by using $S_n$ formula for A.P or by using the above method. Depends on what are you aiming to do further.

Comment: should the last term on the left hand side be $3(n+1)+2$?

Comment: Oh, I see that you're referring to the OP's question. Sorry for the misunderstanding there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you’re attempting the induction step of a proof by induction. The problem is that you’ve not made the change from $n$ to $n+1$ correctly. The next term after $3n+2$ is $3(n+1)+2=3n+5$, not $2(3n+1)+2$, and the new righthand side should be

$$\frac{(n+1)\big(3(n+1)+7\big)}2=\frac{(n+1)(3n+10)}2\;.$$